# Accessing Excel Sheets in Java using Apache POI with Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache

Am a new bee for Apache Poi and Eclipse IDE.. I am in need to work with Excel files where i have to generate a new spread sheets and need to read all the contents of the Excel sheet. so I have stated with a sample code which can generate a excel sheet. Based on requirements I have added poi-2.5.1.jar as external .jar file to the project..
here is the code,

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


 public class Ex1 {

//public Ex1() { }
public static void main(String[] a)
{
    //public Ex1() { }
    try {



        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

        //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first sheet from the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            //For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {                  
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
        FileOutputStream out = 
            new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

 }
```

Now am receiving  "Could not find main Class. Program will Exit" pop up error msg while attempt to run. where could  I do mistakes. please help me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try

right click on your file -> Run as -> Java Application

Comment: Hi Mehul, Do you have any idea about how to read the data of "Merged Cells"?

Comment: This might help http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/How-to-read-single-value-from-merged-cells-td2289494.html